# Long time index recovery when install plugin into existing Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I installed [langdetect](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-langdetect) plugin into Elasticsearch beta cluster that have just 1 node and around 455 indices. When re-start server, use around 5-10 minutes to get yellow status.

I think if this plugin be installed in production that have many nodes and thousand indices. It have to use a lot of time to recovery perhaps.

Anyone used to meet this situation like this? how could you deal with it? Could I re-start ES with zero downtime?

p.s. use ES version 5.3.2

Comment: If the indices don't get any updates anymore, you could take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/indices-synced-flush.html to speed things up a bit. On a side note: generally speaking having thousands of indices is something you want to avoid.

Comment: In your side note, what's it mean, sorry.

Comment: Each index has an overhead: the master needs to communicate about mappings to all the nodes about all those indices every time a new field is added for example, each index has shards which have segments, which need filepointers, etc, etc. Having thousands of indices is, generally speaking, a bad idea and a symptom of a design flaw.